# Is there any specific way to write limit clause in eclipse for neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-java-api

I am have following problems in neo4j eclipse implementation :

1 . I get error with the limit function

```
Code:
      String rows = "";        
    try ( Transaction ignored = graphDb.beginTx();
            Result result = graphDb.execute( "match(pr:Provider)-[t:TREATS]->(p:Problem) return pr.prdes as Name, t.pprcount as Visits, limit 5" ) )
      {
          while ( result.hasNext() )
          {
              Map<String,Object> row = result.next();
              for ( Entry<String,Object> column : row.entrySet() )
              {
                   rows += column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ";
              }
              rows += "\n";
          }
      }
    System.out.println(""+rows);

}

Output:
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Invalid input '5': expected whitespace, comment, node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '[', "=~", IN, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, AS, ',', ORDER, SKIP, LIMIT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 97 (offset: 96)) "match(pr:Provider)-[t:TREATS]->(p:Problem) return pr.prdes as Name, t.pprcount as Visits, limit 5"
```

2. Also it took like 50 mins to execute the above query without the limit clause. So how to increase the performance speed?

Comment: How much data is returned if you run it with out the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a comma before `limits`, try

```
match(pr:Provider)-[t:TREATS]->(p:Problem) 
return pr.prdes as Name, t.pprcount as Visits limit 5
```

instead.

Since this is a global query without a defined start point its execution time will of course depend on your data size.